# FragmentManager getFragments return null

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-support-library

I need some help understanding the underlying of FragmentTransactions and FragmentManager. Im having a NPE thrown whenever I recreate the activity, after a configuration change (screen rotation), and call

```
    List<Fragment> fragments = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments();
    boolean pending = getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Any pending : " + Boolean.toString(pending));
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Size : " + Integer.toString(fragments.size()));
    for(Fragment fragment : fragments){
        if(fragment != null & fragment.isVisible()){
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Fragment Tag : " + fragment.getTag());
        }
    }
```

The sample output looks like this

```
11-14 10:17:42.806: D/MainActivity(1825): Any pending : false
11-14 10:17:42.806: D/MainActivity(1825): Size : 3
```

The stacktrace prints a NPE at the line below because the Fragment is null.

```
if(fragment != null & fragment.isVisible()){
```

Here is my confusion. Before I recreate the activity, I have two fragments in the manager. I attach the third fragment and then remove it, leaving me back to what should be two fragments. However, the manager is saying that there are three fragments in the list. Why is this? I can see the removed fragment go through its onDestroy(). Is the manager keeping a null reference of the fragment?

Comment: Do you know why there is a null entry in the list? I was under the impression that calling FragmentTransaction.remove() would remove the reference to the fragment.

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`list.size()` counts also `null` entries.

So this

```
ArrayList<String> entries = new ArrayList<String>();
entries.add(null);
Log.d("HomeFragment", "Entries " + entries.size());
```

prints this:

```
HomeFragment  D  Entries 1
```